# Python: Platform independent way to modify PATH environment variable

Tags: python, path, cross-platform, environment-variables

Is there a way to modify the `PATH` environment variable in a platform independent way using python?

Something similar to `os.path.join()`?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You should be able to modify `os.environ`.

Since `os.pathsep` is the character to separate different paths, you should use this to append each new path:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path
```

or, if there are several paths to add in a list:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(pathlist)
```

As you mentioned, `os.path.join` can also be used for each individual path you have to append in the case you have to construct them from separate parts.

Comment: What with PATH environment separators ? ?
linux -   /usr/bin:/lib:    ":"
windows - C:\asdf\;C:\Prog...;     ";"

Comment: @bua: do you mean the `os.pathsep` I mentioned (specific to PATH)?

Comment: @RedGlyph Yes, sorry I thought that os.pathsep is "/" and "\".
I didn't check that before claiming ;).

Comment: @bua: It's almost a "gotcha" that `os.path.sep != os.pathsep`.

Comment: @krawyoti, bua: Ah, now I see... well spotted! It's an easy mistake indeed :-)

Comment: I tried this code and to verify if my path added into env. or not I ran another code print(os.getenv('PATH')) and I can see my path in there but I cant see my path when I open system properties => environment variables => path neither as user variable nor system variable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 21):

Please note that `os.environ` is not actually a dictionary.  It's a special dictionary-*like* object which actually sets environment variables in the current process using [setenv](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html).

```
>>> os.environ.__class__
<class os._Environ at 0x100472050>
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["HELLO"] = "WORLD"
>>> os.getenv("HELLO")
'WORLD'
```

This means that `PATH` (and other environment variables) *will* be visible to C code run in the same process.

(Since comments can't contain formatting, I have to put this in an answer, but I feel like it's an important point to make.  This is really a comment on [the comment about there being no equivalent to 'export'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable/1681256#1681256).)

Answer (score 7):

The caveat to be aware of with modifying environment variables in Python, is that there is no equivalent of the "export" shell command.  There is no way of injecting changes into the current process, only child processes.

Comment: +1: Wise to point that out, commands like `os.system`, `os.popen` or `subprocess.Popen` should then be used from the Python application to launch other processes. Otherwise it's pretty much pointless.

Comment: Clarification of Glyph's statement: this is not true because changes *are* injected into the current process (which is the python process). OP likely meant there's no way of injecting changes into the parent process (which is typically a shell that the python script was executed from).

Comment: If that's what OP means, then the shell doesn't have this capability either; `export` causes a variable to be copied into the environment of all *child* processes, but has no effect on the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

You could refresh it like this

```
os.environ["PATH"] = os.environ["PATH"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code snippet. It would be great if you could comment on how exactly it solved the OP's problem so we could all learn from it!

Comment: Some installers modify PATH, some don't. 
For those which do, 
if you need to have current, 
"fresh" env PATH status [at] runtime of your script, 
you can refresh it like this. 
Example:
I was installing gh via script. This installer modifies path.
I needed access to "fresh" env path [at] runtime.
This solution was sufficient.
In other case (not modified PATH), solution posted above is better:
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path.