# Python C API: Modify search path

Tags: python, c

How can I add a speciific directory to the search path using the C API? And a related question: will the changes be local to the application, or is the search path global?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`PySys_GetObject("path")`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/sys.html#PySys_GetObject) to retrieve `sys.path`, then manipulate it as you would [any other sequence](http://docs.python.org/c-api/sequence.html) or [list](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html). Changes will be local to the Python interpreter/VM.

Comment: Why isn't there a PySys_GetPath() in the API?

Comment: There is a PySys_SetPath(const wchar_t *path). https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sys.html

Comment: PySys_SetPath is deprecated since version 3.11.

Answer (score 15):

You can update search path using the [well-known Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081330/how-do-i-modify-the-system-path-variable-in-python-script/4081519#4081519) but called from within your C module:

```
PyRun_SimpleString(
   "import sys\n"
   "sys.path.append('/your/custom/path/here')\n"
);
```