# Pydub unable to locate ffprobe

Tags: python, ffmpeg, libav, pydub

Here is the link to a similar question to this: [Pydub (WindowsError: [Error 2] The system can not find the file specified)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284461/pydub-windowserror-error-2-the-system-can-not-find-the-file-specified)
Although in this one the problem is with ffmpeg, which I solved by setting the absolute path.

After setting the absolute path for converter and/or ffmpeg with either:

`AudioSegment.converter = r'C:\ffmpeg\bin'`

or

`AudioSegment.ffmpeg = r'C:\ffmpeg\bin'`

I still get this error:

> C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:193: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
> warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Sean/Desktop/vp/encode_audio/m4a_to_wav.py", line 4, in 
> song = AudioSegment.from_file("pines.m4a", "m4a")
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 660, in from_file
> info = mediainfo_json(orig_file)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 263, in mediainfo_json
> res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in **init**
> restore_signals, start_new_session)
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
> startupinfo)
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I have ffmpeg in my path envvar. I also have libav in my path envvar, and installed libav and then pydub in the order specified at https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#dependencies.

Nothing I'm doing appears to be working, so any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows
This worked for me with a system reboot after install
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651215/couldnt-find-ffmpeg-or-avconv-python

Comment: Windows: This worked for me with a reboot after install
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651215/couldnt-find-ffmpeg-or-avconv-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I solved it five minutes ago.

Here is the solution:

1. Download ffmpeg file into your computer and install it.
2. Pass the system path of the ffmpeg file location.
   [image]

**(¥ means \)**

I put the file into `C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe`

**(Attention: This is after I changed the filename)**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
AudioSegment.ffprobe ="C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe"
```

Put these lines after the import sentence.

At last, **reboot your computer**

I have suffered from this problem very much, but the problem is solved now.

Comment: This solved the error I was getting. I have long since given up on this and instead just utilise ffmpeg through cmd, but thought I would mark this as answered for those of you who happen to be unfortunate enough to stumble upon this question.

I should mention that this error is now replaced with 
  `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`


This is the only link I could find relate to it: https://github.com/blueset/ehForwarderBot/issues/133

Answer (score 5):

To add on to @Gopesh Kwandelwal's answer

> sudo apt install ffmpeg

an alternative is to have Anaconda or Miniconda installed, then use:
`conda install ffmpeg`

This worked for me when inside a custom environment, and didn't even require restarting the kernel, let alone restarting the computer. (I couldn't comment on that thread b/c I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: First of all, install ffmpeg following the post : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/  Then, apply conda install ffmpeg. It worked for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For Linux/Ubuntu/Debian users:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the step mentioned by @user9402680 but still causing issue. Then I add ffmpeg bin file path location to PATH environment variable. Its working fine now

Comment: Maybe you missed the "`I have ffmpeg in my path envvar. I also have libav in my path envvar, and installed libav and then pydub in the order specified at https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#dependencies.`"

Answer (score 0):

## Mac OS

Mac (using homebrew):

### ffmpeg

`brew install ffmpeg`

## Reference

https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#getting-ffmpeg-set-up