# Pydub can't find ffmpeg although it's installed and in path

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, pydub

I'm attempting to open some MP3 files to find their lengths (as part of a larger project).  I've installed pydub and ffmpeg has been installed via brew.  ffmpeg is available in my path, and typing ffmpeg in a terminal launches it successfully - the audio file I'm referencing is present and I can run ffmpeg -i on it to get information about it.  The program can open and play the audio file (using pygame), so I'm sure it's not a file issue.

However, attempting to open any files with AudioSegment leads to 'Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg but may not work' being displayed, and any attempt to open a file using AudioSegment leads to an exception.

I've tried setting the path to ffmpeg explicitly using AudioSegment.converter - both trying to point to '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' and also to the true location (the previous one is a symlink).

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' # tried with and without
print(len(AudioSegment.from_mp3('mp3_audio.mp3')))
```

I get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'

Comment: You don't need to install anything on a Mac to get the duration of an `mp3` file, the built-in `mdls` command will do that for you `mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds song.mp3`

Comment: Thanks @Mark Setchell, but I need to do it within Python as it's part of a project that will also need to run on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

This was hard work to figure out. But here it is.

On Mac, run `brew install ffmpeg`

Then you need to find where it has written the binary to. It will be buried in `/usr/local/Cellar` directory and will be based on the version number of the install. In my case it was

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.1_2/bin/ffmpeg
```

You then need to add this path into your Python script as follows

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

AudioSegment.converter = '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.1_2/bin/ffmpeg'
```

Comment: Also see this for ffprobe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219531/pydub-unable-to-locate-ffprobe

Comment: if you facing error when installing ffmpeg in macos, use this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464381/9331978