FFmpeg `FileNotFoundError` ([WinError 2]) when probing a video file in Python
I'm encountering a FileNotFoundError with the message [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified when trying to probe a video file using the Python ffmpeg-python library. This occurs despite the file existing, being readable, and having the correct path. I have verified file existence and permissions in my script.
Here's the relevant output and my Python code:
Output:
Checking sample folder contents...

Script location: C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\vid_pro_tool\src\video_processing\video_compressor.py
Project root: C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\vid_pro_tool
Sample folder path: C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\vid_pro_tool\src\video_processing\sample

Directory contents:
- Transformers.mkv (Size: 2988476.97 KB)
  Absolute path: C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\megaProj\vid_pro_tool\src\video_processing\sample\Transformers.mkv
  Exists: True
  Is file: True
  Read permission: True

Attempting video compression...

Processing video:
Input path: C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\vid_pro_tool\src\video_processing\sample\Transformers.mkv 
Exists: True
Is file: True
Read permission: True
Output path will be: C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\vid_pro_tool\src\video_processing\sample\Transformers_compressed.mkv
Error during video probe: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Error type: FileNotFoundError
Video compression failed

Relevant Code:
import os
import sys
import logging
import pathlib
import ffmpeg

class VideoCompressor:
    @staticmethod
    def list_sample_folder_contents(): #List contents of the sample folder with detailed path information

    @classmethod
    def compress_video(cls, input_path: str, filename_suffix: str = 'compressed') -> str:
        try:
            video_path = pathlib.Path(input_path).resolve()
            print(f"Input path: {video_path}")
            
            if not video_path.exists():
                raise FileNotFoundError(f"Video file not found: {video_path}")
            
            output_path = video_path.parent / f"{video_path.stem}_{filename_suffix}{video_path.suffix}"
            print(f"Output path will be: {output_path}")

            probe = ffmpeg.probe(str(video_path))  # Error occurs here
            print("FFmpeg probe successful")
            return str(output_path)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            return False

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    )
    
    try:
        print("Checking sample folder contents...")
        VideoCompressor.list_sample_folder_contents()
        video_path = r"C:\Users\me\A\B\ProjFile\vid_pro_tool\src\video_processing\sample\Transformers.mkv"
        print("\nAttempting video compression...")
        result = VideoCompressor.compress_video(video_path, target_size_kb=500000)  # 500MB target
        
        if result:
            print(f"Success! Compressed video saved to: {result}")
        else:
            print("Video compression failed")
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Main execution error: {e}")
        raise

Problem:
As you can see from the output, the script performs extensive checks to ensure the video file exists, is readable, and the path is correct. However, the ffmpeg.probe() call still results in the FileNotFoundError. This seems to indicate that the error isn't coming from Python's file handling directly, but from ffmpeg or ffmpeg-python library itself.

you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74658329/4516027
