# Ffmpeg on idle python Mac

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFMPEG on idle 3.7.4 python on macOS Catalina.

I ran `brew install ffmpeg` and it successfully installed.

However, when I go to IDLE and run my script (the script is to convert a .mp3 file to a .wav):

```
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment    

src = "transcript.mp3"
dst = "test.wav"         

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
sound.export(dst, format="wav")
```

This is what I get in return:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 165
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 193
    warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edenhikri/Desktop/transcript.py", line 9, in <module>
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 716, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/audio_segment.py", line 665, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py", line 263, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'
```

Comment: can you run `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` in terminal/console without using full path to `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` ?  You may have to ad folder with `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` to system variable  `PATH`

Comment: can you explain this more? @furas

Comment: open console/terminal/bash/xterm window and write `ffmpeg` and press `ENTER` to run it. If it can't run it then it can't find `ffmpeg` and the same problem has `Python`.

Comment: when I do that this is what I get:

Comment: configuration: 
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

Comment: answer in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284461/pydub-windowserror-error-2-the-system-can-not-find-the-file-specified) shows that you could use `pydub.AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "/absolute/path/to/ffmpeg"`

Answer (score 0):

Your python execution environment is not able to find your ffmpeg installation. Because I simply copy pasted your code and it works.

Your error literally says `No such file or directory: 'ffprobe': 'ffprobe'`

There's also a warning: `Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work`

please check the environment in which your script is executing. Maybe IDLE is doing something. Try running your script via the terminal in which you get an output for `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` as:

`python3 script_file.py`