# The system cannot find the file specified - Python Speech Recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1tEy.png)

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...")
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        info = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(info)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

It shows:
`[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

The expected output should be printing all the stuff that I say.

I have already installed PyAudio using pipwin.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185166/python-speechrecognition-cant-find-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by resetting up the path variable for the python interpreter. Thanks for all the answers and your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Hi Install pyaudio using pipwin

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

[image]

Comment: Its working in my machine. Provide some more details if anything missing

Comment: @SakshamAgarwal : Which editor your using, check the installation path or venv path

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, what I did was:

First install pipwin using pip:

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then install pyaudio using pipwin:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```