# update $PATH from python

Tags: python, bash, path

I want to update path from python script i-e add `/tmp` in $PATH. Reason is I am using aws lambda and it looks for `aws-iam-authenticator` binary. Now this binary has to be in $PATH otherwise it throws error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws-iam-authenticator': 'aws-iam-authenticator'
```

Since only `/tmp` is writeable in aws-lambda I can not move this binary to any other `/bin/*` or PATH dir.

I tried doing this:

```
subprocess.call('PATH=$PATH:/tmp/',shell=True)
```

But it doesn't work.

Lambda path:
`PATH=/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin`

Comment: >>> import os
>>> os.environ["PATH"]+="/dodo/"
>>> print os.environ["PATH"]

This seems to work

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea imo. That would that any program you put in your `tmp` folder will be in your `PATH` which may lead to problems when resolving executable real path. A better way to solve your issue would be to move the `aws-iam-authenticator` binary to a folder in your path (`/opt/bin` for instance). You may need to play around with `chmod` and `chown`.

Comment: If you still want to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081330/how-do-i-modify-the-system-path-variable-in-python-script

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the executable using the full path? `/tmp/aws-iam-authenticator`

Comment: If you script relies on `aws-iam-authenticator`, why are you installing it to `/tmp`, rather than somewhere already accessible?