# Appending PATH variable in python does not work

Tags: python

I am modifying the PATH variable using os.environ(),following is the code i am using:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\'
```

the command runs fine and if i show the content of PATH variable using  `os.environ["PATH"]` in python interpreter the modification is being shown i.e(vlc is added to PATH or it seems so):

```
C:\Windows\System32;C:\linuxlikecli;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Falcon\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C
:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mpv.install\too
ls;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java
\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Falcon\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\
Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Falcon\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sys
tem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin;C:\Program Files\Ash;C:\
php-8.0.0-Win32-vs16-x64;E:\Software\_download.org_Burp.Suite.2020.7\Crackdownload.org_Burp.Suite.2020.7;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin
;C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\
```

but whenever i start the `edit environmental vairables` dialog or if i do echo %PATH% in cmd the modification is not being shown(vlc is actually not being added to path):

```
C:\Windows\System32;C:\linuxlikecli;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Falcon\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C
:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mpv.install\too
ls;;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Jav
a\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Falcon\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\S
ystem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)
\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Falcon\MinGW\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\asnlze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin;C:\Program Files\Ash;C:
\php-8.0.0-Win32-vs16-x64;E:\Software\_download.org_Burp.Suite.2020.7\Crackdownload.org_Burp.Suite.2020.7;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bi
n;
```

note that i am refreshing the environment after setting it,what's wrong in my implementation,any help is appreciated .i am using python3.8 on windows 7 64 bit.tried it with admin and without admin shell

Comment: You are changing "session" env. It will not change anything else, else sessions' nor system wide settings

Comment: also please give a reason for downvoting

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski then how should i change the PATH variable

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41171179/15151511)  answer we can change the PATH the way i did

Comment: It's important for context purposes that you define what you are trying to achieve with this piece of code. Are you trying to change the system-wide PATH variable forever? or are you just trying to add this to your PATH for the purposes of this script? More details would help

Comment: What do you mean by `i start the edit environmental vairables dialog`? This is in cmd, powershell, vscode or some other setups?