# How to add a directory to System path variable in Python

Tags: python

I am running python 3.9 on Windows.

```
print(sys.path)
currDir = os.getcwd()
currDir += "\node"

sys.path.append(currDir)
print(sys.path)
```

I see the 2nd print out of `sys.path` has my `c:\working\node\`

But my issue is when I run the command under `c:\working\node\`, e.g. `npm install`

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["npm.cmd", "install]),
```

I get error saying 'The system cannot find the file specified'

And after my script is run , I try 'echo %PATH%', I don't see `c:\working\node\` in the %PATH% varaible too?

Can you please tell me how can I add a new directory to system path variable so that `subprocess.Popen` can see the new addition?

Comment: `sys.path` is just a list and you are appending, you not modifying anything.

Comment: `"\node"` is the word "ode" with a newline in front of it.

Comment: `sys.path` has **nothing to do with** the operating system's `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.path` is not the same as the `PATH` variable specifying where to search for binaries:

> [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)
>
> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

You want to [set the `PATH` variable in `os.environ`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41171179/2658436) instead.

```py
app_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'other', 'dir', 'to', 'app')
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'node')
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the name, [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) is NOT the system PATH. It is (from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)):

> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

Additionally, any changes to the environment won't propagate to a new process you open w/in a python session unless you tell it explicitly to do so.

You can solve both of these with the [`env` flag of `Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)
You can get the current environment from `os.environ`, then simply extend the PATH variable and pass this environment through to `Popen` via the env flag

Something like:

```py
new_env = os.environ.copy()
new_env['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join((new_env['PATH'].split(os.pathsep) if 'PATH' in new_env else []) + [currDir])
p = subprocess.Popen(["npm.cmd", "install"], env=new_env)
```

Additionally, make sure you are properly escaping your paths on Windows if using backslash, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/4582273) for more details

```py
currDir += "\\node"
```