# Error during subprocess calling ls

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, ls, dir

any idea what is the error trying to say?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `ls` command on windows, which doesn't have an `ls`. You can grab a port of `ls` for windows from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm and add it's installed bin dir to your windows `PATH` (or add it to PATH at run time of your python script. if you dont know how to to do this, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable/1681244#1681244) question respectively).

`dir` is the windows equivalent, but it will print differently formatted output compared to `ls`, and presumably, this call is to get some kind of information from a directory. There are better ways to do this in python. If you can identify what information it is trying to get (e.g. permission bits), then you might be able to write a pure python version of this (or find an equivalent python snippet for windows that does this) and not rely on external commands.

Interestingly, `subprocess.call()` simply runs the command and returns the error code. `ls` itself just prints information, so if that is the intent (just to show the user a directory's contents in a console), then you can replace it with a call to `dir`. Sometimes, you will need to provide `shell=True` as a parameter depending on the command you are calling. Pay attention to the [warning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) in the documentation though. If it is trying to extract information, it probably wants to do a `subprocess.Popen()` or `subprocress.check_output()` style call, where you actually can consume the called program's output.

If for example, it is just to get the list of files/directories in a directory and/or their timestamps, then this is a very round-about way of getting this information, and they can all be done in python itself e.g. [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), [`os.fstat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat), and in Python3, [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#) are some ways to get file information in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute the `ls -l` command on Windows. `ls` will only work on Unix-based systems.

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
```

If you're on Windows, try

```
subprocess.call(["dir"])
```

instead.

Alternatively, you could try something like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: i did try your code "subprocess.call(["dir"])" but it still shows the same error (i am on windows by the way)

Comment: do i need to make a PATH?

Comment: Depending on how subprocess.call is implemented, it might need to be "cmd /c dir" since dir is a builtin, not an executable.  But it would be far more sensible to use Python's own file-management functions.