# rpy2: No output when importing R libraries that are not standard R libraries

Tags: python, rpy2

I want to use the rpy2 package. When I import R's PortfolioAnalytics library which does not belong to the standard library, I do not get any output anymore. (I run my python code directly from Idle on Windows and not via the Windows console (because of the problem I outlined below).)

Examples:

**First code works fine:**

```
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

    print 'check output 1'
    utils = importr("utils")        # 'utils' belongs to the standard lib

    print 'check output 2'
```

**Output:**

```
    check output 1
    check output 2
```

So far so good. But in the following example it will not work anymore.

**Second code does not work:**

```
    import rpy2.robjects as robjects
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

    print 'check output 1'
    utils = importr("PortfolioAnalytics", lib_loc = "C:\username\Documents\R\win-library\3.3")

    print 'check output 2'
```

**Output:**

```
    check output 1
```

**Additional note:**
I am not sure whether the following is connected to the problem: When I want to execute my code using the Windows Console , I get the error

```
    RuntimeError: R_USER not defined.
```

(I have added R's bin directory to the PATH variable.) Anyways, that is not my urgent problem. I only wanted to add this information in case it might be connected to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a comment, but I can't write comments yet.

I tried to reproduce your error, which I couldn't. Here are my thoughts:

1. During installation of R on Windows I was forced to set R_USER. I don't know how you got around that, but I think it is a good idea to do so. 
    
   There are different versions of R available. The newest one (R 3.3.0) does  store the R.dll in the directory specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698877/how-to-setup-enviroment-variable-r-user-to-use-rpy2-in-python), which is were R_HOME supposedly should point to. I have seen at other places people using higher directories (`.../R/R-x.y.z/`) or different directories (`.../R/R-x.y.z/bin/i386`). If it causes problems, you might want to try one of those.
2. It also seems to be a good idea to add the directory containing the R.dll to your PATH variable.
3. The last thing I can think of concerns your usage of lib_loc. While the documentation of `rpy2` states, that this option to `importr`should point to the library, the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/index.html) of Portfolio Analytics states, that the package has to be compiled. Unlikely as it may be, could it be that your package is not installed via (for instance) `install.packages("PortfolioAnalytics")`, or at least not correctly? In that case your `lib_loc` value might point to the correct directory, but the library is not actually compiled.

Approximately what I did:

1. Install R
2. Install Python
3. Download and install the [visual c++ compiler for python](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
4. Set the `R_HOME` and `R_USER` environment variables and add the directory containing R.dll to my `PATH`.
5. Use the R command line to install PortfolioAnalytics (and all its dependencies) with `install.packages("package_name")` taking into account the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa).

After that, running your code worked for me without errors. (Tested from command line, IDLE and Eclipse (PyDev) on Windows 10 with Python 2.7 and R 3.3.0.)

If this doesn't help you, maybe you can share some more information on what you have tried so far.

Edit: I was able to partly reproduce the described behavior and it seems to be related to the usage of `lib_loc`. There seems to be no detailed documentation for `importr` and also not for the usage of `lib_loc`. After making sure that the package was installed correctly, I tried to specify its location with the `lib_loc` argument. The following directories all turned out to be invalid values for this purpose:

- /R_DIR/library
- /R_DIR/library/PortfolioAnalytics
- /R_DIR/library/PortfolioAnalytics/libs
- /R_DIR/library/PortfolioAnalytics/libs/x64
- /R_DIR/library/PortfolioAnalytics/libs/i386

That's all I checked. However, I am fairly sure, that installing the package into `/R_DIR/library` (which works best, if R is not installed in any system directory like `Program Files`, due to Windows restrictions) should make it unnecessary to specify `lib_loc`. If I am correct, that is a viable workaround, especially if you are just starting to set up your R environment.

Actually a different issue and already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090981/error-during-subprocess-calling-ls) has occurred during the `importr` command (I think) at some point. As explained in the link this is related to the missing `ls` function in Windows and solved for me by Preet Kukreti's answer.