# How to check if a Git Repo has uncommitted changes by gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I tried

```
g = git.Repo(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\testRepo')
print g.untracked_files
```

But got:

> git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: [Error 2]

Is it a bug?

Comment: Which versions of git and gitpython are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have this error when I do exactly the same.

Do you have `git` executable in your ${PATH} variable?
If you are using bash you can run
`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/git/executable`

From `exc.py` in `gitpython`:

`class GitCommandNotFound(Exception):
    """Thrown if we cannot find the`git`executable in the PATH or at the path given by
    the GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE environment variable"""
    pass`

one can assume that setting that env variable may also help.

You can also set env variable directly from python in platform-independent way as greatly described here, instead of modifying your startup script (aka ~/.bash_profile or similar ):

[Python: Platform independent way to modify PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable)