# how to get PATH environment variable separator in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

in python i can use

```
  import os
  os.pathsep ===> ':' for unix, ';' for windows.
```

how can i get the same in nodejs?

for now i am asking if platform is win32 or not

```
 process.platform === 'win32' ? ';' : ':' ;
```

i want to achieve the same as asked : [Python: Platform independent way to modify PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable) but in nodejs.

Comment: please use os npm for this                                                                            https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

Comment: os.platform() is the function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var path      = require('path');
var delimiter = path.delimiter;
```

See also [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_delimiter).