# Why can't the 'system' function in Linux run this shellscript?

Tags: linux, shell, command, argv

I meet a problem about system function. If I run

```
echo -e '\x2f'
```

in shell,the output is `/` but when I put the command in C program like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char** envp)
{
    printf("The command is :%s\n",argv[1]);
    system( argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
The command is :echo -e '\x2f'
-e \x2f
```

Why does the `system` function output '`-e \x2f`' instead of '`/`'

BTW, I use Python to input the argv:

```
# I used \\ because python will transfer \x2f to / automatially
command="echo -e '\\x2f'"
p=process(executable='/home/cmd2',argv=   ['/home/cmd2',command])
print (p.readall())
```

Comment: Because the script is run by `/bin/sh` and not by `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` doesn't interpret things the same as `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `echo` command can output differently between `sh` and `bash`.
Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/escape-sequences-with-echo-e-in-different-shells

```
bash -c "echo -e '\x2f'"
# Output : /
sh -c "echo -e '\x2f'"
# Output : -e /
```

In order to have Python spit out the same, something like below should work.
(For your reference, included the same implementation with subprocess)

```
import os
import subprocess

command = "echo -e '\\x2f'"

os.system( command )
# Output : -e /
subprocess.call( command , shell=True )
# Output : -e /

bashcmd = "bash -c \"echo -e '\x2f'\""

os.system( bashcmd )
# Output : /
subprocess.call( bashcmd , shell=True )
# Output : /
```

I am uncertain of how you got `-e \x2f` as your output though.

Comment: `bash -c \"echo -e '\x2f'\"` can work but my situation is that PATH variable has been emptied,so I use `echo -e '\x2f'`to construct `/`,but `/bin/bash` also have `/`,Maybe I should try another way

Comment: Are you trying to set PATH variable ground up? It may be worth checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1681244/7153181) out. In any case, `echo` is probably not the way you want to take...