# When trying to Complie Yolo,I'm getting package not found error

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I trying to use yolo for object detection, but when i try to compile it, i get this error:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

i mean its a really long error,but i guess this is the essence of it-
i have tried setting the environment variable to the opencv path,
here are the specifics

```
locate opencv.pc
/home/decentmakeover2/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc    
/home/decentmakeover2/anaconda3/pkgs/opencv-3.1.0-
np111py35_1/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc

echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH 
:/home/decentmakeover2/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc
```

Im not exactly sure how to proceed.

Comment: want to explain,why the downvote?or are you just bored?

Comment: You can try to use os.environ as stated in this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable

Comment: thanks,will check this out

Answer (score 0):

Add the *directory* that contains opencv.pc. So /home/decentmakeover2/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig