# Export a variable from Python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

In shell script , I'm able to export a variable. How do I do the same in Python

Shell code:

```
PYTHON_PATH=`which python`    
PYTHON_PATH=`dirname $PYTHON_PATH`    
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin    
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH:$PYTHON_PATH
```

Python code:(Version - 2.7)

```
PYTHON_PATH = subprocess.check_output("which python", shell=True)    
PYTHON_PATH = os.path.dirname(PYTHON_PATH)    
PATH = os.path.expanduser('~') + "/.local/bin:" + PATH + ":" + PYTHON_PATH    
subprocess.call('export PATH="{}"'.format(PATH), shell=True)
```

Is this right way to export a `PATH` variable in python.

Comment: simple print of sys.path is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question (credit: [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable))?

```
import subprocess
import os

PYTHON_PATH = subprocess.check_output("which python", shell=True)    
PYTHON_PATH = os.path.dirname(PYTHON_PATH)    

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + PYTHON_PATH.decode()
```