# Define path using python

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I am using the program GTDBtk, a tool kit that uses other programs. When I ran GTDBtk using the terminal it gave me an error:

```
[2020-03-15 18:58:22] INFO: Using GTDB-Tk reference data version r89: /Users/Desktop/GTDB/gtdbtk/release89
hmmsearch is not on the system path.
```

I solved this problem by writing this code

`PATH="/Users/monkiky/Desktop/Data/hmmer-3.3/src/hmmsearch:$PATH"`

Now, due to I need to run this program several times, I am writing a script in Python. Writing this code I have found the same error and I do not know how to solve it.

```
[2020-03-21 11:26:37] INFO: Using GTDB-Tk reference data version r89: /Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/gtdbtk/release89
hmmsearch is not on the system path.
```

How can I define the path using python? or what I am doing wrong.

I have tried this with not lucky:

```
os.system('PATH="/Users/monkiky/Desktop/Data/hmmer-3.3/src/hmmsearch:$PATH"')
```

Here my completed coded:

```
#Define directory
os.chdir('/Users/monkiky/Desktop/prueba/GTDBTk-1.0.1')

# We define the environment variable
os.environ['GTDBTK_DATA_PATH'] = "/Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/gtdbtk/release89" 

# Add the path of prodigal (here the problem bust be)
sys.path.append("/Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/GTDBTk-1.0.1/hmmsearch")


#Run the program
os.system('gtdbtk identify --genome_dir /Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/input --out_dir /Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/prueba')
```

output

```
2020-03-21 14:29:09] INFO: GTDB-Tk v1.0.2
[2020-03-21 14:29:09] INFO: gtdbtk identify --genome_dir /Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/input --out_dir /Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/prueba
[2020-03-21 14:29:09] INFO: Using GTDB-Tk reference data version r89: /Users/monkiky/Desktop/GTDB/gtdbtk/release89
hmmsearch is not on the system path.
[2020-03-21 14:29:09] ERROR: Controlled exit resulting from early termination.
<built-in function chdir>
```

Comment: `os.system` starts a new shell, executes the assignment in that shell, and then that shell exits. `PATH` in the *current* process isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to append your path to the PATH, then use

```py
import os
path = '/Users/monkiky/Desktop/Data/hmmer-3.3/src/hmmsearch'
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + path
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable).

Alternatively, you can either:

Add `/Users/monkiky/Desktop/Data/hmmer-3.3/src/hmmsearch` to your system environment manually (let's call it `HMM_SEARCH_PATH`) and the call:

```py
import os

path = os.getenv('HMM_SEARCH_PATH')

# Use path wherever you need, e.g.
print(path)
```

or,

Create a `.env` file in your project folder and insert 
`HMM_SEARCH_PATH = /Users/monkiky/Desktop/Data/hmmer-3.3/src/hmmsearch`, then in your python script:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
path = os.getenv('HMM_SEARCH_PATH')

# Use path wherever you need, e.g.
print(path)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values) and this [article](https://preslav.me/2019/01/09/dotenv-files-python/) for more information.

Comment: The question says what the OP wants to do with the path: add it to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Sorry. I have tried with all your advice but I got the same error. I am going to change the question and add my completed code