# How to add a directory to PATH variable before running anything in Pytest or Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, path, pytest

Adding a directory to the PATH variable can be as simple as running `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`. What I'm trying to achieve is to have pytest run this command before anything else happens so that I can set the browser drivers to PATH (instead of moving them to `/usr/local/bin` as I prefer to change PATH temporarily).

Couple obvious workarounds are:

- Manually executing the above command before starting pytest
- Using a separate Python file to wrap around pytest

My attempt after looking through several SO posts was to play around with various `pytest_` methods such as `pytest_configure` in `conftest.py` but this did not work as pytest failed to see the specified directory in PATH.

Is there a way to incorporate this command into pytest framework so I don't have to explore these workarounds?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1681208/2650249

Comment: @hoefling Unfortunately, this is equivalent to `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir` with `os.system` wrapped around it, which I initially mentioned in the post. I'm trying to find a way within the Pytest/Selenium framework to set the PATH before running tests or spinning up Selenium drivers. Please help!

Comment: `conftest.py` gets run before any test does.  Following the procedure @hoefling links in the top-level `conftest.py` should have the desired effect.

Comment: @KyleParsons As mentioned in the original post, setting the PATH variable via `pytest_configure(config)` method in `conftest.py` did not yield the desired effect because the Selenium drivers were spun up before the new PATH was set