# How to direct a python package to a user install library rather than a root library?

Tags: python, django, pyodbc

I install python packages to my user root directory since I can't install it to the root directory due to security issues.

The python package (pyobdc) is looking for `/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib` which doesn't exist there but it exists at `/Users/Max/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib`.

I wanted to create a syslink but of course I ran into the same issue which is permissions to root.

How can I make the package (Installed in a Django project) point to the user root?

Comment: Just add `/Users/Max/usr/local/lib` to your python environment path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable

Comment: The package is still looking for the same location.

`'/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Comment: Can you check that you added your directory in front of the system's directory? Many places add to the end by default, which wouldn't work for this.