# Why do i get error when using HLS4ML with Vivado HLS, Vivado installation not found

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, vivado-hls

i have installed Vivado 2019.2 on my computer running on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I have installed hls4ml on Google colab.

i have also specified the Vivado installation path

```
os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/gegerin/Vivado_HLS/Vivado/2019.2/bin' + os.environ['PATH']
```

i followed the tutorial here: [hls4ml github tutorial/ Code i ran](https://github.com/fastmachinelearning/hls4ml)

https://github.com/fastmachinelearning/hls4ml

However, when i run the command : hls_model.build()
i get the following output

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Exception Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
4 os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/gegerin/Vivado_HLS/Vivado/2019.2/bin' + os.environ['PATH']
5
----> 6 hls_model.build()
7
8 #Print out the report if you want

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/hls4ml/model/hls_model.py in build(self, reset, csim, synth, cosim, validation, export, vsynth)
548 found = os.system('command -v vivado_hls > /dev/null')
549 if found != 0:
--> 550 raise Exception('Vivado HLS installation not found. Make sure "vivado_hls" is on PATH.')
551
552 elif backend == 'Intel':

Exception: Vivado HLS installation not found. Make sure "vivado_hls" is on PATH.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: One thing I see is a missing separator between the new path for `PATH` and the existing ones.

Comment: Can you please point out where, i am very new to this and appreciate your help

Comment: The paths in the "PATH" environment variable are separated by `:` on Linux (better use "os.pathsep" for portability) Your new string for "PATH" directly prepends the existing paths so that it is merged with the following path to an invalid result.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, i ran: os.pathsep['PATH'] = '/home/gegerin/Vivado_HLS/Vivado/2019.2/bin' + os.pathsep['PATH']  and the result is : TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-83f40fe98d03> in <module>()
      2 #This might take several minutes
      3 import os
----> 4 os.pathsep['PATH'] = '/home/gegerin/Vivado_HLS/Vivado/2019.2/bin' + os.pathsep['PATH']
      5 
      6 hls_model.build()

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Colab on some Google cloud server, then **you won't have Vivado HLS available** (since it's not installed there, but just locally on your machine).

Maybe you can try running Colab locally ([guide](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)).

Please also check this [github issue](https://github.com/fastmachinelearning/hls4ml/issues/430).

## Edit

Now I see it. I think you're wrongly appending the Vivado path to PATH, as it's missing the path separator:

```py
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + '/home/gegerin/Vivado_HLS/Vivado/2019.2/bin'
```

Please check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681208/python-platform-independent-way-to-modify-path-environment-variable).

Comment: I also tried jupyter notebook ...so thats on my computer.. it should have worked but i get the same output i.e. vivado installation not found ..  the GitHub link is routing to my question lol . I posted it , in hopes of solving this issue

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried what you said and it worked. God bless you man. i'll never forget this.